# автоматическое срабатывание onclick (js)

Tags: javascript

нужно реализовать скрипт который будет:

1. автоматически срабатывать событие onclick при попадании на страницу
2. в блоке div сообщать о срабатывании

---

```
 <a id="ssilka" onclick="myFunction()">123</a>
<div id="info"></div>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'событие сработало';
    }
</script>
```

в таком виде код срабатывает только при нажатии, как автоматически запустить onclick?

Comment: После объявления функции добавьте 4-ю строчку `myFunction();` ? `()` — это оператор вызова функции, не обязательно кликать, чтобы она срабатывала...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое: надо дождаться загрузки страницы и только после этого вызывать функцию клика. Для этого можно воспользоваться событием [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    document.getElementById('ssilka').click();
});
```

При срабатывании события, нужно найти нужный элемент на странице и произвести клик по нему программно (ну или, как говорится, сделать триггер событие клика)

```
// выделение callback функции в отдельную....функцию :)
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onDocumentReady);

function onDocumentReady(e) {
    document.getElementById('ssilka').click();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'событие сработало';
}

setTimeout(() => ssilka.click(), 1000);
```

```html
<a id="ssilka" onclick="myFunction()">123</a>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Comment: это именно то что нужно

Comment: Какой setTimeout? неправильно

Comment: @Юрий это некорректный ответ.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, это по причине зацикленности таймера?

Comment: @Юрий это в принципе по причине использования таймера. Во-первых есть специальное событие, которое помогает дождаться загрузки страницы. Во-вторых: страница может загружаться дольше, чем 1 секунду и тогда функция не сработает